# Add an extra lib folder dependency to build sbt in a lift project

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I have an external java project that my lift project depends on. I have been able to add the dependency to the classes in that project by adding the following line to my sbt:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += file("[Path to My Project]/classes")
```

But this project also has a lib folder with a set of jars that it references and I cannot figure out what the correct syntax should be to add these dependencies. Have tried the following but it does not work:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("[Path to My Project]/lib/*.jar")
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Regards

Des

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sbt's [Path API](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths.html) to get all jars in your directory.

**Edit**: a shorter version using `.classpath`:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= 
  (file("[Path to My Project]/lib/") * "*.jar").classpath
```

which is more or less equivalent to:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= 
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("[Path to My Project]/lib/") * "*.jar").get)
```

(`Attributed` is necessary because `unmanagedJars` is a setting of type `Seq[Attributed[File]]` and not `Seq[File]`)