# Add a lib to java.library.path with Scala and SBT?

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface, sbt, java.library.path

I am using the Play Framework and Scala. I need to add a Java library that has some JNI libraries dependencies. On their site they say to put the native libraries in `java.library.path`. How do I add the native libraries to an SBT project using Scala?

Comment: Additionally see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524109/sbt-cross-platform-way-to-set-java-library-path

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as an [unmanaged dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940120/add-an-extra-lib-folder-dependency-to-build-sbt-in-a-lift-project), or just put the JAR into a /lib folder under your project root.  It will then be available on your classpath.

Comment: [This](https://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/wiki/GettingStarted) is the library I am using. I am able to add the the jar file to the lib folder as an unmanaged dependency but I am not able to load the native library, the `.so` file using the `java.library.path`.

Comment: In my humble experience, sometimes, the native `.so` file is loaded not from within the jar, in which case it needs to be available flat on disk in a place your runtime or JVM can find it, otherwise we get the same error even though the jar is well found and loaded (and _does contain_ a copy of the `.so` file).